# Using Terminal Command while Running Anaconda on Macbook

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, pip, jupyter-notebook

While my Jupyter Notebook is running, the terminal shows that it is saving files periodically. How to run "pip install" using command lines in the terminal while the Jupyter Notebook is running? I believe I need to find a way to get back to the "~ username $:," from which I can type commands. I tried 'cd/' but it didn't seem to work.

So far I've been closing out of Anaconda, finishing "pip install", and getting back into Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a unix-type system. In that case you can

1. In the jupyter notebook do `!pip install <whatever package it is>`
2. In the terminal window, type `^Z` and then `bg`, then type your `pip install` command.
3. Open another terminal window, and do your `pip install`.